# how does irb require work?

Tags: ruby, irb

Typically when I am testing small snippets of code for Ruby, I many times put code chunks in separate files in the same directory, run irb, and then run the following command:

```
Dir[Dir.pwd + "/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

Which loads all the files into irb. Which brings me to my question: when I require a file, how does irb process that request? Does it take all requires and put them in one overall 'file' ? I am looking for the mechanics of how irb works.

If anyone has the answer or can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/ericmathison/articles/blob/master/understaning-require-in-ruby.md

Comment: Thank you. That article was really helpful and what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

`require` loads a file into the Ruby interpreter. The source code is analyzed, its by-products incorporated into the Ruby runtime (classes loaded, etc.), and then the source code is not saved anywhere and is eventually garbage collected (the memory it occupied is freed).